# Because project depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk which depends on intl 0.16.1, intl 0.16.1 is required

Tags: flutter, intl, pubspec, flutter-localizations

Okay so i have built an app nearly a year and half ago for my company, my boss recently wanted me to add a new screen to it and i did using all old and deprecated code of firebase and everything else (i really really dont wanna update them because i know everything nearly changed and building a whole new app would be better than editing this lol, so i'm trying to avoid that option), the app runs on Android just fine, but it doesnt build on ios and it does not allow me do "flutter build ios" in the terminal giving above error when trying to build ios or trying to pub Get.

Granted my `intl version` was `^0.16.1` , then it would say that it requires `0.17.0` , then I changed it based on another post here to `intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2` but it gives the  output above. what's the problem?

Here is my Pubspec.yaml:

```
name: tamatafreshiq
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment: 
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+2
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  flutter_spinkit: ^3.1.0
  english_words: ^3.1.5
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  provider: ^4.1.3
  firebase_storage: ^4.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+2
  image_cropper: ^1.2.3
  url_launcher: ^5.4.11
  localization: ^0.1.0
  cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1
  fluttertoast: ^6.0.1
  badges: ^1.1.3
  data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2




dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/gifs/
    - assets/languages/
  fonts:
    - family: Rabar
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rabar_014.ttf
    - family: Rubik
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik-Light.ttf
```

Comment: what's the error the other way around?  In other words:

> then it would say that it requires 0.17.0

What specifically is requiring that? Probably not just flutter_localizations and intl in a loop...something else should be involved.  You have a really old localization plugin as well...wonder if that's the error on the other side?

Comment: same error: Because tamatafreshiq depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.17.0, intl 0.17.0 is required.
So, because tamatafreshiq depends on intl ^0.16.1-nullsafety.2, version solving failed.

Comment: i try to change localization to the newest "1.1.1, it gives this error: Because tamatafreshiq depends on localization >=0.2.0-nullsafety which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.

Comment: sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"  see how that helps.  I'm just guessing.

Comment: then it says : the current Dart SDK version is 2.9.0-13.0.dev.flutter

Comment: honestly i commented out the localization package in the pubspec, and it still gives the same error, so i don't think its related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade your flutter version on your local machine to flutter 2.0+ now cause you are importing null safety supported dependency which uses dart sdk 2.12.0 but you have 2.7.0 which is making conflict with the other dependencies. If you do have 2.0+ already then upgrade the sdk of your app from pubspec.yaml. You will then have to update your code to full sound null safety starting from upgrading all the dependencies then the code, its not that hard even if your app is using firebase I get my apps upgraded to null safety within a week. Once all gets sorts out you'll have no trouble with your project in importing some null safety dependency or some else more importantly you will be able to have better performance of your app and can keep all the dependencies to support latest versions and might possible you app will be android 12 ready too

Comment: i deleted old flutter and downloaded the latest one, moved files into new project and  updated them all to null safety and now it's working again ! :)